# Recreate Similar Travis CI Console Log Interface

Tags: css, ember.js, travis-ci

The first time I saw the [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) live updating build console log, I was, I'll admit, nerdily impressed. And I know with some very time consuming CSS styling and JS coding, I could probably get something half as nice. But, my question is, are there any libraries out there that would make building something like this easier? I realize that Travis CI uses Ember as their web app framework, but I'm guessing this isn't a component of Ember, right?

[image: Travis CI Console Log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"travis-web" uses Ember, but the functionality for the "log-container" is custom.   It contains the text of the log file ("Download Log"). Please download a raw version of a log and take a look.

You will see, that the log file has several "annotations". It's a syntax to indicate the areas, where some custom styles are applied.
These lines are processed by the [Log script](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/7229e068c51a60ff2fef401dac527fa8b0d911db/vendor/log.js) and then removed.

Ok, let's decompose this:

**► Code-Folds**

Folds start with `"travis_fold:start:section_name"` and end with `"travis_fold:end:section_name"`

The content inside the fold is placed in a span.
By default the span height is 0. Initially the content is not shown.

On-click, the additional css-style `open` is added to the span. 
The style `open` sets the `height` of the span element to `auto` - and the content of the fold will show up.

**Line-Numbers `://url#L100`**

The annotations are removed form the log file content

(`total number of lines = raw log file lines - annotation lines`).

All lines numbers are anchor elements (`a`), so line-wise referencing is possible.

The numbering itself is done by CSS - the number is added before the anchor.

`log-body p a::before {
  content: counter(line-numbering);
  counter-increment: line-numbering;`

**Colors**

Throughout the raw log file ansi-color codes are used.
The content is parsed by the [AnsiParser script](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/7229e068c51a60ff2fef401dac527fa8b0d911db/vendor/ansiparse.js) and the color-codes are converted (deansi'ed) into their css-class color names.

The string

`[0K[33;1mBuild system information[0m`

becomes

`<span id="1-3" class="yellow bold">Build system information</span>`

**Scroll-To-End-Of-Log & Move to Top**

Scroll-To-End-Of-Log is similar to scroll to end of div: `this.scrollIntoView(false);`

When scrolling is activated, the activation button itself is top positioned to keep it at the same spot.

The "move to top" is bottom positioned.

**Active Line Hovering**

The current cursor line is styled with `p:hover: #color`.

**Section and Duration Display**

On the right side the "section or folder name" and the "duration" is show.
Both are spans based on the following markers:

`travis_time:start:0759cab0`

cmds

`travis_time:end:0759cab0:start=1434311411734827664,finish=1434311413318517466, duration=1583689802`

---

> But, my question is, are there any libraries out there that would make building something like this easier?

For a small site, you could use a themeable Javascript based CodeEditor, like CodeMirror.

Apply a dark-theme, add some custom rules for code-folding and code-highlighting, active-line hovering. This will get you pretty close in no time.

- https://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html
- https://codemirror.net/demo/folding.html

Comment: Any Idea how they do the # percentage? How do they consolidate the the entire loading into a single line?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this: (a) interval fetch of a text/log file, where the content is written to the same position/line in the file, (b) on a terminal with ansi escape codes, (c) linux cli `echo -ne` with carriage return `/r`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12628501/1163786