# How to echo strings at the same position?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I built my web server and I'm trying to do a test. So I simulate many requests with bash script:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
    echo ''
    echo ''
    echo ''
    echo '============== current time ==============='
    echo $i
    echo '==========================================='
    echo ''
    curl -i http://www.example.com/index?key=abceefgefwe
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

This works well but I prefer to make all of `echo` at the same position on the terminal.
I've read this: [How to show and update echo on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628327/how-to-show-and-update-echo-on-same-line)

So I add `-ne` for `echo` but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
The messages of `curl` can still push the `echo` away.

This is what I need:

```
============== current time =============== ---\
1   <------ this number keeps updating      ----> the 3 lines stay here
=========================================== ---/
Here is the messages of `curl`, which are showing as normal way
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a simpler way to solve this, but `ncurses` library you can achieve what you want.

Comment: @sid-m   OK  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another option, to position the cursor before you write to stdout.

You can set `x` and `y` to suit your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

y=10
x=0
i=0
while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
    tput cup $y $x
    echo ''
    echo ''
    echo ''
    echo '============== current time ==============='
    echo $i
    echo '==========================================='
    echo ''
    curl -i http://www.example.com/index?key=abceefgefwe
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `clear` command at the beginning of your while loop. That would keep the echo statements at the top of the screen during each iteration, if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Maybe you could pipe curl to head/tail -n 30 to control the number of lines output and keep it from printing enough to push the header off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

When I do this sort of thing, rather than using curses/ncurses or `tput`, I just restrict myself to a single line and hope it doesn't wrap.  I re-draw the line every iteration.

For example:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
  curl -i -o "index$i" 'http://www.example.com/index?key=abceefgefwe'
  printf "\r==== current time: %2d ====" $i
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

If you're not displaying text of predictable length, you might need to reset the display first (since it doesn't clear the content, so if you go from `there` to `here`, you'll end up with `heree` with the extra letter from the previous string).  To solve that:

```
i=$((COLUMNS-1))
space=""
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
  space="$space "
  i=$((i-1))
done
while [ $i -lt 20 ]; do
  curl -i -o "index$i" 'http://www.example.com/index?key=abceefgefwe'
  output="$(head -c$((COLUMNS-28))) "index$i" |head -n1)"
  printf "\r%s\r==== current time: %2d (%s) ====" "$space" $i "$output"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

This puts a full-width line of spaces to clear the previous text and then writes over the now-blank line with the new content.  I've used a segment of the first line of the retrieved file up to a maximum of the line's width (counting the extra text; I may be one off somewhere).  This would be cleaner if I could just use `head -c$((COLUMNS-28)) -n1` (which would care about the order!).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below..

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\033[s" 

echo -e "\033[u**Your String Here**"
```